# Se podra hacer una barra progresiva y hacer que abance segun el tiempo transcurrido?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Literal lo que dice la pregunta, queria empezarlo en html y javascript pero no tengo idea de como empezarlo.

tengo esto pero no hace lo que quiero si no que hace un conteo que se reinicia cuando recargas la pagina

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }

};
progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
```

```
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle     aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[Codigo sacado de este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320242/progress-bar-countdown-doesnt-work)

La idea esencial es que una ves puesto en funcionamiento en una pagina online empiece el conteo que dure por ejemplo 5 dias y que muestre el porcentaje que lleva

Como los countdown pero en ves de que aparezca el tiempo en horas que sea una barra progresiva

Editado:
Encotre algo parecido se puede ver en este [link](https://jsfiddle.net/45hx6m2j/)

Como lo ven que le añadirian por ejemplo para que aparesca unas llamadas de atencion cada 20%??

Comment: Tu contador será individual por cada equipo que abra tu pagina?

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con una base de datos, ya sea del lado del cliente o del servidor

Comment: Necesitas un backend que te ayude a controlar el tiempo, recuerda que el navegador es memoria volátil que desaparece cuando recargas o cierras la pestaña. Podrías guardar los valores en local storage, pero si el usuario limpia datos de navegación, tendrás problemas.

Comment: Aquí logre hacer la barra fue hecho con php https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401646/me-podran-guiar-con-esta-barra-progresiva-con-php"