# Me podran guiar con esta barra progresiva con php?

Tags: php, css, html5, css3, progressbar

Hola estoy un poco trabado con esta linea de tiempo, la idea que quiero es que cuando llegue a cada punto aparesca el texto como viene en cada punto de la siguiente imagen: [image: Linea de tiempo]

Aqui tengo el codigo que encontre investigando en internet, es simple y no tiene estilos, y no logro acceder a cada tiempo que tiene en $eventDays, me imagino que si los llamo con javascript podria hacerlo pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo, alguien podria guiarme para ver que podria hacer?

```
<?php 

$startDate = "26-10-2020";
$endDate = "30-10-2020";
$eventDays = ['Monday', 'Tuestday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
$startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
$endDate = new DateTime($endDate);
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$progress = 0;
if($currentDate >= $startDate){
    $totalDays = 0;
    $pastDays = 0;
    while($startDate <= $endDate){
        if(in_array(date('l', strtotime($startDate->format('d-m-Y'))), $eventDays)){
            $totalDays++;
            if($currentDate >= $startDate) $pastDays++;
        }
        $startDate->modify('+1 day');
    }
    $progress = round($pastDays * 100 / $totalDays);
}

 ?>
```

```
    <h2>Progress Bar Event | <?php echo $startDate->format('d/m/Y').' - '.$endDate->format('d/m/Y'); ?></h2>
    <p style="width:<?php echo $progress; ?>%" data-value="<?php echo $progress; ?>">Event progress:</p>
    <progress id="prog" max="100" value="<?php echo $progress; ?>" class="html5">
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <span style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%"><?php echo $progress; ?>%</span>
        </div>
    </progress>
```

Comment: Has intentado algo con javascript hasta ahora ¿? Sino, primero intenta, y deten o avanza la barra en donde la necesites. -> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

Comment: wow la verdad que no conosco mucho de javascript pero con eso me guiaste muy bien ya pude hacerlo te lo agradesco mucho!

Comment: Comparte tu mismo tu propia solución al problema, y luego podrás marcarla como tu respuesta ;) Lo importante es que lo aprendiste de tu mano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilice este codigo, lque mediante la llamada window.onload se carga en automatico al iniciar la pagina y muestra los letreros segun el porcentaje que lleve la barra progresiva

```
$var i = 0;
window.onload = function move() {
    if (i == 0) {
        i = 1;
        
        if(document.getElementById("prog")) {
            var width = document.getElementById("prog").value;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {  
                if (width >= 20){
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Estamos Trabajando en tu Análisis de Sitio';
                }
                if (width >= 40){
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Estamos Trabajando en la Logística de tu Proyecto';
                }
                if (width >= 60){
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Estamos Trabajando en el Equipamiento de tu Propiedad';
                }
                if (width >= 80){
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Estamos Trabajando en el Diseño de tu Propiedad';
                }
                if (width >= 100){
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = '¡Listo! Ya Puedes Descargar tu Proyecto!';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```